# How to explore transaction chain via Original Bitcoin API as blockexplorer does it

Tags: transactions, api, json-rpc, blockexplorer

Is there any possibility to explore transaction chain via Original Bitcoin API (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_Calls_list) as the blockexplorer does it.
If not, why?